# Sendind a GET / POST requests to an API in Android Studio

Tags: android, http

I updated my manifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and tried to google how to send simple http get request with android, found plenty of different answers, most of them outdated using depraced methods.

How do I send HTTP GET / POST to my API URL, for example `http://www.apiawesome.com/getData`?

My API returns JSON array inside a JSON object.

My Code:

```
private void loadData()
    {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.myapi.com/api/loadData");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            readStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
}

can't resolve method readStream.in()
```

Comment: Show us your research

Answer (score 1):

Do not use HttpURLConnection or Volley, [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) is the way to go. Modern, efficient, easy to use and fast. It's a real diamond.

Comment: `private void connect()
    {
        @GET("users/list")
    }` "Anotations are not allowed here", I'm really new to this, but why I get this error? The website is not documented in beginner friendly way

Comment: @TheUnreal Yes, Retrofit is a "higher skill" library, but if you give it a couple of hours, you will like it a lot. I recommend you this tutorial, it is for the new 2.0.0 version. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Updated Code for POST and for get add the params in url

```
  HttpURLConnection httpcon=null;
                    try{
//Connect
                        httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));
                        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
                        httpcon.setDoInput(true);
                        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization",clientkey);
                        httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        httpcon.connect();
//Write


                        JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
                        try
                        {
                            object.put("to","/topics/"+topic.trim());
                        }catch (Exception e){}
                        JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
                        try
                        {
                            data.put("message",message);
                        }catch (Exception e){}

                        try
                        {
                            data.put("extmess",messageevent);
                        }catch (Exception e){}

                        try
                        {
                            object.put("data",data);
                        }catch (Exception e){}

                        OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
//            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                        writer.write(object.toString());
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        os.close();

//Read
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

                        String line = null;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }

                        br.close();
                        result = sb.toString();

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        try {
                            int statusCode = httpcon.getResponseCode();
                            Log.e("",""+statusCode);
                        }catch (Exception eee)
                        {
                            eee.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to make HTTP requests in android is using Google's own Volley library

You can refer to these sources to see how to use the library:

1. [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
2. [Sending a Simple Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)
3. [Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)
4. [Android JSON parsing using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)
5. [An Introduction to Volley](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)

Except for these resources the library is very simple to use and plenty of documentation online

Comment: Volley is not owned by Google. Google recommends Glide library and Volley